# Why converting error "data type varchar to bigint" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

After running the query

```
select
ID__F__EMPLOYEE
FROM
DBSCHBI_QUAL.dmHR.[415_Abwesenheiten]
inner join DBSCHBI_QUAL.dwhLay1.DIM_EMPLOYEE
on DIM_EMPLOYEE.ID__F__EMPLOYEE = [415_Abwesenheiten].PersNr
where 1 = 1
and DIM_EMPLOYEE.LastName ='1'
and DIM_EMPLOYEE.ID__F__EMPLOYEE =1
;
```

in SQL-Server I get the error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 218 Error converting data type
> varchar to bigint.

Why do I get this error? Both fields **ID__F__EMPLOYEE** and **PersNr** are bigint and also do not contain any null value.
I can run below queries without any problem:

```
select
ID__F__EMPLOYEE
FROM
DBSCHBI_QUAL.dmHR.[415_Abwesenheiten]
inner join DBSCHBI_QUAL.dwhLay1.DIM_EMPLOYEE
on DIM_EMPLOYEE.ID__F__EMPLOYEE = [415_Abwesenheiten].PersNr
where 1 = 1
and DIM_EMPLOYEE.LastName ='1'
--and DIM_EMPLOYEE.ID__F__EMPLOYEE =1
;
```

Why does the condition

```
--and DIM_EMPLOYEE.ID__F__EMPLOYEE =1
```

makes the query fail?

I can use this condition when I do not join

```
select
ID__F__EMPLOYEE
FROM
--DBSCHBI_QUAL.dmHR.[415_Abwesenheiten]
--inner join
DBSCHBI_QUAL.dwhLay1.DIM_EMPLOYEE
--on DIM_EMPLOYEE.ID__F__EMPLOYEE = [415_Abwesenheiten].PersNr
where 1 = 1
and DIM_EMPLOYEE.LastName ='1'
and DIM_EMPLOYEE.ID__F__EMPLOYEE =1
;
```

and it works.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the source "tables" is in fact a view containing a conversion that can fail? If possible, please provide a [mcve]. You can use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to create one.

Comment: Backing up the comment by @Heinzi, can you run this _to completion_ (scroll to the bottom of the rows) without error? `SELECT * FROM DBSCHBI_QUAL.dmHR.[415_Abwesenheiten]`

Comment: Side note, don't create the [mre] and then *just* put it on a fiddle; include the [mre] in your question as well. Questions should be complete on their own, and putting the example on an external site doesn't do that.